# How to convert string to lower case using ASP

Tags: html, asp.net

I am working on creating an asp page that inserts different forms based on an attribute in HTML

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="insert" widgettype="weather">
    <span id="result"></span>
</div>
```

The person can enter widgettype as 'weather' 'google' or 'webster' depending on what they want to display.

Here is my asp page.

```
<%widgetType=request("widgetType")
    if widgetType="weather" then%>
    <form id="widgetForm">
        <label>Weather Widget</label><br />
        <input name="q" id="zip" />
        <button id="getWeather" onclick="serialize(); return false;">Run</button>
    </form>
    <%end if


    if widgetType="google" then%>
    <h2>Google Search</h2>
<script>

(function () {
    var cx = '007423897740083764505:zdr6tqpd1yq';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>

    <%
    end if
     if widgetType="webster" then%>

        <h2>dictionary search</h2>
        <form id="lookUpForm">
            <input name="q" id="websterInput"  />
            <button onclick="webster(); return false;">Search</button>
        </form>
    <%end if%>
```

I want to make this bulletproof. So I want the asp page to covert the string of 'widgettype' to all lowercase before running the if statement. I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Can you explain your downvote please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB has an LCase function to do this:

```
widgetType = LCase(request("widgetType"))
```